# CouchDB: schema-driven data entry UI

Tags: schema, couchdb

Is there a tool (I suspect something like this exists for SQL databases) that will allow me to define a schema and build a data-entry UI that users will fill out to push data to couchDB?

Ideally, this would look like this:

1. I define a data schema (XML or anything, that's not important how) something like:

Name,
Short description,
Color,
Image (attachment).

It does not have to support data types, length, image size or any other validations.

1. There is UI that will display fields of each of the data fields that users can fill out and click a button.
2. A document is created in couchDB.

Futon does not seem to suit here since it's data entry process is schema free, besides, I haven't figured how to attach files in it and I don't want to users to learn all the woodoo.

Many thanks for all your ideas on this.

Comment: Great idea, have you built it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no magic tool to create a UI for a Couch database from a schema definition.  However, you can certainly write a [CouchApp](http://couchapp.org/pages/Index) or any sort of web application to display the UI however you write it.  There are drivers for Couch and RoR, so you could generate a scaffold that way, but again currently there is no scaffold generator for Couch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything like this working out of the box. There is a json schema out there but it's rather fresh technology and there is no UI tools to automate it's use.

The quickest work around is to use XML for CouchDB documents data: http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2008/03/couchdb-xml-and-e4x

In this case you can:

1. write XML Schema for your docs
2. use an editor with xml schema support
3. bulk upload results to CouchDB with simple script

The other way to do it is to build custom editor using any rapid UI framework you are comfortable with. By a coincidence I'm building such an editor for my work project using Adobe Flex/Air right now.